# NgRx: Correct way to dispatch an action with data dependency

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

Currently, in my project using NgRx, [I have a facade](https://auth0.com/blog/ngrx-facades-pros-and-cons/#:~:text=Facades%20in%20NgRx,-Recently%2C%20there%20has&text=A%20facade%20is%20basically%20just,methods%20on%20the%20facade%20service.) that contains some functions:

```
LoadMyData()
{
    dispatch(MyActions.LoadMyDataAction({ SomeDependentData }))
}
```

I also have

```
  myDependentData$ = this.store.pipe(
    select(MySelectors.GetMyData)
  );
```

What is the right way to get and pass value to `SomeDependentData` from `myDependentData$`? Or there should be some improvement in this design?

One of my colleagues says that I should be implementing an effect that catches my action and resolve the selector then feed the resolved value to the same action, Is this approach possible / good / bad?

Comment: I would dispatch LoadMyDataAction() without payload and resolve dependencies at the reducer level.

Comment: Thanks. So there should be no depedency at this level and let the reducer do the glue-ing instead?

Comment: This is the gray area. You could argue that this is a side effect, therefore you should utilize @ngrx/effects, however by design effects should only care about fetching external data from the servers.

Comment: On the other hand, you're already implementing facade pattern, which already holds dependent data you need. As long as you're not doing it at the component level, it's fine. If you have too many abstractions in your code, readability and maintainability suffers.

Answer (score 1):

Depends, using a [selector in an effect](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/start-using-ngrx-effects-for-this#4-using-a-selector-inside-your-effects) works. 
Another option is to unwrap the selector's value in the template (using the `async` pipe) and pass it along to the load method:

```
LoadMyData(data: any)
{
    dispatch(MyActions.LoadMyDataAction({ SomeDependentData, extra: data }))
}
```